# Почему значение обоих ползунков меняются одновременно?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Делаю два и более слацдера диапазона на одной странице но произошла не понятная мне ситуация! При изменении ползунка на одном меняется и на другом

Присваивать id приведёт к разрастанию кода а хотелось бы одну подобную функцию что бы иметь такой же эффект то есть два и больше слайдеров на странице

Как можно сделать что бы работало 2> range на странице ?

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".custom .range").forEach(function (elem){
  let data = document.querySelectorAll(".custom .view .data");
  data.forEach(function (values){
    elem.addEventListener("input", function (){
      values.innerHTML = this.value + "%"
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<div class="custom">
  <div class="view"><div class="data">1%</div> </div>
  <input type="range" class="range" min="1" max="100" value="1">
</div>

<div class="custom">
  <div class="view"><div class="data">3%</div></div>
  <input type="range" class="range" min="1" max="100" value="3">
</div>
```

Возможна ли эта реализация на html + css ?

буду признателен за подобный пример

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы каждый раз пробегались по всем элементам с процентами. Такой вариант решает проблему, но я не думаю, что это лучший вариант.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".custom").forEach(function(elem) {
  let data = elem.querySelector(".data");

  elem.querySelector('.range').addEventListener("input", function() {
    data.innerHTML = this.value + "%"
  })
})
```

```html
<div class="custom">
  <div class="view">
    <div class="data">1%</div>
  </div>
  <input type="range" class="range" min="1" max="100" value="1">
</div>

<div class="custom">
  <div class="view">
    <div class="data">3%</div>
  </div>
  <input type="range" class="range" min="1" max="100" value="3">
</div>
```

Comment: меня устраивает ! спасибо